# Prevent Windows 7 from reading bad disk sector and freezing

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, freeze, bad-sectors

My hard drive has a couple of bad spots, and Windows pretty much stops everything to try to read that one spot it fails on. As in, the taskbar and mouse pointer actually freeze. I know it's trying to read one spot because I can hear a steady pattern from my hard drive, for about 10 minutes at a time. I really can't do anything while it's going.

So, my question is: If it's possible, how do I either make it give up, or not try as many times? I can deal with it if it only freezes for 30 seconds at a time, but this is getting ridiculous.

Comment: A program like SpinRite might help but your had is failing time to replace it

Answer (score 3):

Run your HDD manufacturer's utility and see if it can remap those bad sectors. If required you might need to run `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt to repair any damaged OS files.

Common sense dictates that you start taking regular backups if you haven't done so already, and replace the drive ASAP.

Comment: and you should perform a 'chkdsk /R' on the drive to attempt to remap the bad sectors, and do a SMART test to determine whether this is actually a disk problem. lastly, growth in the SMART 'Reallocated Sector Count' stat is usually a very steep graph, so replacing a hdd after it accumulates more than a couple bad sectors have been detected is a good idea.

Comment: A through/deep scan by the HDD manufacturer's utility *should* take care of business and rescanning with chkdsk shouldn't be required in addition. It's never a good idea to place a failing drive under even more stress. Good point about the SMART stat though.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with @Ramhound and suggest you should run [SpinRite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) to identify, recover, and move data from those bad sectors and correctly update the S.M.A.R.T data. I would also agree with @Frank Thomas and @Karan in suggesting you replace the drive before your wish of a catastrophic failure occurs...

Comment: If there isn't an update to spinrite since the last version I owned (about 4 years back), this will take - at current hd sizes - ages; and isn't even that good for modern hdds. That said, can't hurt, but spinrite isn't what it uses to be (best tool for this).

Comment: Other than SSD's, the basic spinning media (i.e., hard drive) technology hasn't changed, they've only increased capacity...

Comment: Agreed, but it's also size-restricted - not even to speak of how long it would take if it weren't. Even the Wikipedia article - flagged as 'reads like a product advertisement' aka, written by Gibson or a fan - mentions that it is restricted to 128/255Gb - not large these days. I own the license, and used to be fan; I just think times have passed it by. If it still works fine for your needs (and maybe OP's), all the better. :)

Comment: @gnometorule Really? You haven't offered a single solution or suggestion to the OP...explain how SkylarMT can resolve the issue and quit haten on SpinRite!